# Unnecessary window is opened when I start sublime text 3 from terminal <Ubuntu 18.04>

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext, ubuntu-18.04

I installed *sublime-text* on *Ubuntu 18.04* via *apt*.

The problem is that when I run

```
$ subl *path*
```

to start sublime text from terminal, **2** windows are opened.

1 window shows the directory at the specified path.

However, the additional window is also opened, 
which is the latest window I closed.

I do not need the latter window.

Has anyone faced such an issue and resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `subl -h` to display all utility options and find one that can fit your needs... Maybe `subl -a path` would solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! 
In my case, `subl` shows a previously closed window, so `subl -a` shows a mixed window of a previously closed directory and a specified directory.
I found the same question and the issue is resolved. 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: can you add link to this resolved issue, maybe yours is a duplicate?